# Autofill a cell based on two other values

Tags: vlookup

For table 1 cell P1 (Rate - 1505.18) i entered that value in manually based on data in the same row Column I and Column K and referring to the Discounted Rate card tab to work out the rate.

I tried writing a vlookup in Table 1 Cell P93 instead so it searches for it automatically but i keep getting an error. Can someone please tell me what am i missed from the following Vlookup that is causing the error?

=VLOOKUP(I99, 'Discounted Rate Card'!D18:H211, MATCH(K99, 'Discounted Rate Card'!E18:H18, 0), FALSE)

[image: Table 1]

[image: Discounted Rate Card]

Comment: Take out `match`. The formula should be `=VLOOKUP(I99, 'Discounted Rate Card'!$D$18:$H$211, K99 + 1, FALSE)` so `I99` is the row and `K99` is the column.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(I99, 'Discounted Rate Card'!$D$18:$H$211, K99 + 1, FALSE)

Comment: I tried the above statement but i still get a N/A error

Comment: The formula looks correct. Please upload your document (or sample) for me to test with.

Comment: how do i upload it?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/doce33

Comment: uploaded to a public url. Hope it works....

Comment: Thanks for the upload. The lookup text does not match. That's why the lookup returns `N/A`. Copy the text from both fields into Notepad and compare. You will see the issue.